# Spark graphFrames - Label Propagation vs. Strongly Connected Components

Tags: apache-spark, graphframes

In the https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/graph-analysis/graphframes/user-guide-scala.html standard example:

- The Strongly Connected Components seem reasonable computationally when looking also at them visually on a drawing.

[image]

- Therefore I am surprised at the Label Propagation for detecting "communities".

[image]

What am I missing? [A, D, E] I would have thought would be a community as well from the data and that results would be similar. I tried with more cycles.  Label Propagation seems the poor cousin of "clustering".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have found here is a known phenomenon called label oscillation which occurs when the labels are synchronously updated and (sub)graphs have a bipartite structure (or star graphs). The two communities will endlessly exchange their labels and the LPA will never terminate by itself.

**Labels at t:**
[image: oscillation at t]

**Labels at t+1:**
[image: oscillation at t+1]

**Labels at t+2:**
[image: oscillation at t]

... and so on.

As you have already mentioned this is not really what we would expect from a community detection algorithm as there are no edges within the communities. But this is still a fast algorithm which delivers good results for non bipartite structures. [Raghavan](https://dollar.biz.uiowa.edu/~street/raghavan07.pdf) proposed a fast alternative which uses  asynchronous updating. But this is not yet implemented in Graphframes. Graphframes calls the graphX implementation of LPA (have a look at code [code](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/graphframes/lib/LabelPropagation.scala)) which uses Pregel (have a look at code [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/graphx/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/graphx/lib/LabelPropagation.scala)) which is synchronous.

Besides of LPA problem for bipartite structures there is also a **general difference between SCC and LPA**:

- SCC community: Every node of a community knows (has an edge) all other nodes within the community.
- LPA community: For each node of a community there is a path
  (sequence of edges) within the community to all other nodes within
  a community.